# App Scoped User ID open in app Ios

Tags: ios, facebook

I have an app scoped user id fetched from Facebook with the sdk.

How is it possible to open the user profile in app?

If I share the id with my friend and he opens `fb://profile?app_scoped_user_id=...` then it opens to his own Facebook account, but not mine. Is it possible to do this? If yes, then how?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for App Scoped IDs is to protect the privacy of the User. It would be pointless if you could just link to the real profile of the User, as you would be able to get his real ID quite easy with the profile link (by just replacing "www" with "graph") - and you could see his public posts too.

What you CAN do with an App Scoped ID: Get the Profile Picture of the User: http://graph.facebook.com/[app-scoped-id]/picture

Comment: Yeah I know, it's because of the privacy. But it has to be possible to share it I guess? So that you can open it from another device?

Comment: just because of privacy, it would be weird if it would be possible to share the profile or get access to it.

Comment: Yeah, but I think you don't get my intention. I try to share just so you can visit his profile and you can send a friend request. Not do anything else about it.

Comment: that´s already a privacy issue ;) - not sure why you would want to do that over an app anyway, to be honest...

Comment: Yeah it's like sharing a contact.

Comment: ...which would be a major privacy issue. access to the profile of a user via app would make the app scoped id useless, as it protects his privacy.

Comment: So it is not possible what I'm trying to do? 

You give access to it if you login?